# Varying the complete electromagnetic action

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, action, variational-calculus

To obtain the Lorentz force law, it is sufficient to vary:

$$S=\int d\tau \sqrt{\eta_{\mu\nu} \frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau} \frac{dx^\nu}{d\tau}}+A_{\rho}(x)\frac{dx^{\rho}}{d\tau}{d\tau}$$

and get:

$$\frac{d^2x^{\epsilon}}{d\tau^2}=F^\epsilon_{ \sigma} \frac{dx^\sigma}{d\tau}$$

Which is the relativistic Lorentz force law.

But this is not the complete action. The action has an extra term:$$d^4x \frac{1}{4} F^{\mu\nu} (x)F_{\mu\nu}(x)$$

which is dependent on $x$. I'm unsure how to vary it as there is $d^4x$ and not $d\tau$, but this is not a reason to ignore it. Does varying it with respect to $x$ have zero effect?

Comment: Varying with respect to the field gives you Maxwell's equations with the currents determined by the particle path $x^\mu(\tau)$. This is fairly standard, see most QFT books for details.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this. I'm talking about varying with respect to position. Does the maxwell lagrangian have no effect?

Comment: Oh, I think you're just confused about notation. The quantities you vary with respect to are the dynamical variables $A^\mu(x)$ (field as a function of spacetime) and $x^\mu(\tau)$ (position of particle as a function of its proper time). The two $x$'s are completely different: one is a dynamical variable, the other is just a dummy variable. You never vary with respect to the $x$ in $A^\mu(x)$ just like you wouldn't vary with respect to $\tau$.

Comment: Indeed, the FF term is not function of particle position. This confusion is also a good reason to use different symbol for particle position coordinates, say $r$ (radius vector), and different symbol for spacetime coordinates, say $x$.

Comment: Oh, this solves 90% of my problem. I remember confusing this before. What I'm still confused about is when I apply Euler Lagrange equations, shouldn't this not be a problem? Why can't we partially differentiate $F^{\mu\nu} (x)$ with respect to position? Is this because of the$d^4x$ not being $d\tau$? can't we convert $d^4x$ to $d\tau$?

Comment: We *can* partially differentiate *F* wrt to spacetime coordinates $x$.

Comment: But when expressing the EL equations for particle coordinates and velocities, the FF term gets differentiated wrt to particle coordinates and velocities, and those derivatives are zero.